# Js returns only the first row of the table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
  function builTable(){
    for(i = 0; i< source.Products.length; i++){

      var sourceProducts = source.Products[i];
          row = '<tr><td>sth</td><td>';
          row += sourceProducts.Product;
          row += '</td><td>';
          row += sourceProducts.Bookings + '</td><td>';
          row += sourceProducts.Percentage + '%' + '</td><td>';
          row += sourceProducts.Transactions + '</td></tr>';

          return row;

    }

  }

  function generateTable(){
    $('table').append(builTable());
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){

    generateTable();

  });
```

This only appends the first row of the table however if I change it to the following:

```
  function builTable(){
    for(i = 0; i< source.Products.length; i++){

      var sourceProducts = source.Products[i];
          row = '<tr><td>sth</td><td>';
          row += sourceProducts.Product;
          row += '</td><td>';
          row += sourceProducts.Bookings + '</td><td>';
          row += sourceProducts.Percentage + '%' + '</td><td>';
          row += sourceProducts.Transactions + '</td></tr>';

       $('table').append(row);

    }


  }

  $(document).ready(function(){

    builTable();

  });
```

it works fine, I would like have a more structured code having functions serving their purpose:

- one function for building the table and one for appending it (as shown in the first example).

JSON format:

```
var source = {
    "Products": [
        {
            "Product": "xxxxx.com",
            "Bookings": 560,
            "Percentage": 55.82,
            "Transactions": "xxxx.xx"
        },
        {
            "Product": "xxxxx Mobile",
            "Bookings": 487,
            "Percentage": 9.12,
            "Transactions": "xxxx.xx"
        },
        {
            "Product": "xx 24-7",
            "Bookings": 478,
            "Percentage": 8.95,
            "Transactions": "xxxx.xx"
        },
        {
            "Product": "xxxxxx",
            "Bookings": 422,
            "Percentage": 7.9,
            "Transactions": "xxxx.xx"
        },
        {
            "Product": "API",
            "Bookings": 315,
            "Percentage": 5.9,
            "Transactions": "xxxx.xx"
        },
        {
            "Product": "API",
            "Bookings": 315,
            "Percentage": 2.83,
            "Transactions": "xxxx.xx"
        }
    ],
    "Total": {
        "Bookings": 315,
        "Transactions": "xxxx.xx"
    }
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function builTable(){
    var table = "";

    for(i = 0; i< source.Products.length; i++){

      var sourceProducts = source.Products[i],
          row = '<tr><td>sth</td><td>';

      row += sourceProducts.Product;
      row += '</td><td>';
      row += sourceProducts.Bookings + '</td><td>';
      row += sourceProducts.Percentage + '%' + '</td><td>';
      row += sourceProducts.Transactions + '</td></tr>';

      table += row;

    }

    return table;
  }

  function generateTable(){
    $('table').append(builTable());
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){

    generateTable();

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because `row` is reset every time the loop begins again.

```
function builTable(){
    for(i = 0; i< source.Products.length; i++){

      var sourceProducts = source.Products[i];

          // here is the culprit
          row = '<tr><td>sth</td><td>';


          row += sourceProducts.Product;
          row += '</td><td>';
          row += sourceProducts.Bookings + '</td><td>';
          row += sourceProducts.Percentage + '%' + '</td><td>';
          row += sourceProducts.Transactions + '</td></tr>';

          return row;

    }

  }
```